# Customizing Google Play Newsstand feed

Tags: google-currents

On Google Play Newsstand, I can select feeds for "My news" section, and when I select "Read now", I get a list of news from my selected feeds, and some news not from my selected feeds.

Is there any way I can customize the "Read now" feed and block publications or topics, etc? Or just get news from my selected feeds in the "Read now" section?

Comment: Even if I try to remove all the built-in subscriptions and just have my feeds, this app still bombards me with uninteresting junk in its "Read now" view. Anyone have a guide to getting it to show nothing but rss feeds nicely mixed together (sorted by time)? It would be a very pretty feed reader if not for all that news spam.

Comment: Flipboard does it but I much prefer the newsstand app

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Google Play Newsstand has been discontinued since 2018 and replaced with Google News.

Answer (score 0):

I am just now configuring My News on my tablet. Each news source tile has a setting menu on the far right next to its name (3 vertical dots). Pull that down by clicking, and select "Remove" from the menu, if you do not wish it any longer. Mine came with 12 pre-configured tiles, which I turned off way.

It is easy to add them back from the "Featured" list if you decide later to return to that news source.

UPDATE:I'm not seeing any direct removal of stories of the removed news sources when I first return to "Read Now", but I believe I must click through to expire the stories already presented, and then refresh to have the content cleared.

UPDATE2: Well, that's annoying. There could still be a number of items in the queue from the first opening of the app with pre-selected news sources. I may have to click through them all to see when my preferences will be adopted.

Comment: Thanks but my read now section shows content outside of my selected items in my news.  So Im looking to remove added items to my news section if you have for that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can only remove the sources that you've added manually (via the My News tab). It seems Newsstand is more of a discovery app, so it keeps putting in new stories from new locations based on your reading habits. I've been using it for a few months and it certainly has begun to know me a lot better, but then, I like receiving recommendations and discovering stuff.

One thing I can't seem to remove is the purple and orange background stories, which, for me, seem to be local, current affairs and sports topics, which I'm not interested in. This is because you can add a new source by clicking the '+' at the end of the story, but there's no '-' button to specifically remove a story that you don't wish to receive. The only way is to ignore stories/sources you don't want to read and hope that they'll go away.

Comment: Yeah thanks.  I felt that and ive specifically not read a specific news source that I want to go away.  But it wont.  The headlines are relevant to the stuff I do read and thats why i think it keeps appearing.   the journalism of the site is shocking and there can still be discovery with the ability to remove.  Also an option to show all news from your selected sources rather than individual feeds would also be nice...

Comment: Maybe your best bet is to + the sources you do want to read from and only read the My News section. This will mean that you wont discover new sources, but at least you can keep the unwanted ones out.

Comment: But then I have to read each source individually.  I like the read now where it shows all sources together.  I want the best of both read now and my news!

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that. I guess that's the reason I don't spend much time in the My News section! BTW, you can go into my news and remove the topics (at the end) in which you're not interested. I just removed a few. But not specific sources within topics.

Comment: Remove topics? From read now or my news?  I didnt add any topics just feeds, and i dont see how to remove topics?

Comment: From My News, which directly affects the Read Now sources and discovery.